# Get max number Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data in database, the primary key is the field `SEQ`, I wish to select the data which has the maximum `seq`:

```
ID     SEQ   FILE
1007   1     abc
1007   2     def
```

The following query is invalid but I wish to do the same thing as following.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = '1007' AND Max(seq)
```

Comment: my ID is in varchar2, and my SEQ is in NUMBER

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in a `varchar` column?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT id, seq, file
FROM ( 
   select id, seq, file, 
          max(seq) over (partition by id) as max_seq
   from table1 
   WHERE id = '1007'
) t 
where seq = max_seq;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you wish something like this

```
select * 
from (select t.*, 
      max(t.seq) 
        keep (dense_rank first order by t.seq desc) 
        over (partition by t.id) max#
from table1 t) 
where seq = max#
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
select id,seq,"FILE" from 
(select t1.*,row_number() over (partition by id order by seq desc) cont_seq 
from your_table t1)
where cont_seq = 1
order by seq;
```

This will give you all rows grouped by id who has the max seq value. If you want an specific value just add the condition in the where clause like this:

```
select id,seq,"FILE" from 
(select t1.*,row_number() over (partition by id order by seq desc) cont_seq 
from your_table t1)
where cont_seq = 1 and id = '1007'
order by seq;
```

Answer (score 0):

`select * from alber.table1;`

MYID       SEQ                    FILENAME

---

1007       2                      abc
1007       10                     def
1008       45                     abc
1008       9                      def

`SELECT myid, seq, filename from alber.table1 mq
where seq = (select max(seq) from alber.table1 sq where sq.myid = mq.myid);`

MYID       SEQ                    FILENAME

---

1007       10                     def
1008       45                     abc